# Officejs BubbleChart- Scale bubble size and set axes value scale

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have created a bubble chart following sample at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/blob/main/samples/excel/10-chart/chart-bubble-chart.yaml

I would like to know how to set via api. A code snippet would be helpful.

1. Axes Scale - X axis value changes by 1

[image]

2. the bubblescale property- Control the size of the bubble by adjusting scale
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [Excel Add-ins with Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-charts) to get some information, and Chart APIs details are in [Excel Chart APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.chart?view=excel-js-preview) page, you could refer to Axis and Series sections.

I have added a function `changechartproperties` base on your snippet: https://gist.github.com/donlvMSFT/3169ad1cb17bde3b04a35f19125a87eb, wish could help.

Comment: thank you . Can you let me know how to set bubbleScale property? When i try  it, i keep getting error?